typeorm returns invalid byte sequence for encoding
i am using PostgreSQL db and sometimes when i am getting data i am facing

"exact error facing : invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0"

i know this can happen when inserting, due to miss encoding, but i have no idea, the solution i have is just restart pm2 service and then error disappear for sometime.
Backend : nestjs
process manager : pm2
db ver: PostgreSQL 15.7
any advise
  async getAllLicense(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const items = await this.find({
        relations: { wfloType: true, lookupStatus: true , licensesClassfication:true  },
        order: { license_id: 'ASC' },
      });
      return items;
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        status: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        messageEn: 'Error retrieving items',
        messageAr: 'خطأ في جلب العناصر',
        error: error.message,
      };
    }
  }

complete error
query: 'SELECT "License"."licenses_id" AS "License_licenses_id", "License"."license_ar" AS "License_license_ar", "License"."license_en" AS "License_license_en", "License"."wflo_type_id" AS "License_wflo_type_id", "License"."licenses_classfication_id" AS "License_licenses_classfication_id", "License"."created_by" AS "License_created_by", "License"."last_updated_by" AS "License_last_updated_by", "License"."created_date" AS "License_created_date", "License"."last_updated_date" AS "License_last_updated_date", "License"."status" AS "License_status", "License__License_wfloType"."created_by" AS "License__License_wfloType_created_by", "License__License_wfloType"."last_updated_by" AS "License__License_wfloType_last_updated_by", "License__License_wfloType"."created_date" AS "License__License_wfloType_created_date", "License__License_wfloType"."last_updated_date" AS "License__License_wfloType_last_updated_date", "License__License_wfloType"."status" AS "License__License_wfloType_status", "License__License_wfloType"."wflo_type_id" AS "License__License_wfloType_wflo_type_id", "License__License_wfloType"."name_en" AS "License__License_wfloType_name_en", "License__License_wfloType"."name_ar" AS "License__License_wfloType_name_ar", "License__License_wfloType"."final_email_notify" AS "License__License_wfloType_final_email_notify", "License__License_wfloType"."final_sms_notify" AS "License__License_wfloType_final_sms_notify", "License__License_wfloType"."valid " AS "License__License_wfloType_valid ", "License__License_lookupStatus"."lookup_detail_id" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_lookup_detail_id", "License__License_lookupStatus"."lookup_detail_ar_name" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_lookup_detail_ar_name", "License__License_lookupStatus"."lookup_detail_en_name" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_lookup_detail_en_name", "License__License_lookupStatus"."status" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_status", "License__License_lookupStatus"."created_by" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_created_by", "License__License_lookupStatus"."created_date" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_created_date", "License__License_lookupStatus"."last_updated_by" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_last_updated_by", "License__License_lookupStatus"."last_updated_date" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_last_updated_date", "License__License_lookupStatus"."lookup_id" AS "License__License_lookupStatus_lookup_id", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."licenses_classfication_id" AS "8e46c0678ea314f98067cf187c049d051caa0c39", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."licenses_classfication_ar" AS "fb5dde8942ccb4d0ad04254537a2a7fba0ad2d23", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."licenses_classfication_en" AS "0627108520845c530702b5184949cc19b9d1d5bc", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."created_by" AS "License__License_licensesClassfication_created_by", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."last_updated_by" AS "License__License_licensesClassfication_last_updated_by", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."created_date" AS "License__License_licensesClassfication_created_date", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."last_updated_date" AS "License__License_licensesClassfication_last_updated_date", "License__License_licensesClassfication"."status" AS "License__License_licensesClassfication_status" FROM "license"."license" "License" LEFT JOIN "workflow"."wflo_type" "License__License_wfloType" ON "License__License_wfloType"."wflo_type_id"="License"."wflo_type_id"  LEFT JOIN "admin"."lookup_details" "License__License_lookupStatus" ON "License__License_lookupStatus"."lookup_detail_id"="License"."status"  LEFT JOIN "license"."licenses-classfication" "License__License_licensesClassfication" ON "License__License_licensesClassfication"."licenses_classfication_id"="License"."licenses_classfication_id" ORDER BY "License"."licenses_id" ASC',
1|jhdms  |   parameters: [],
1|jhdms  |   driverError: error: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0
1|jhdms  |       at /jhdms/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:526:17
1|jhdms  |       at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
1|jhdms  |       at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/jhdms/backend/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:260:25)
1|jhdms  |       at SelectQueryBuilder.loadRawResults (/jhdms/backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:3805:25)
1|jhdms  |       at SelectQueryBuilder.executeEntitiesAndRawResults (/jhdms/backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:3551:26)
1|jhdms  |       at SelectQueryBuilder.getRawAndEntities (/jhdms/backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:1670:29)
1|jhdms  |       at SelectQueryBuilder.getMany (/jhdms/backend/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:1760:25)
1|jhdms  |       at LicenseRepo.getAllLicense (/jhdms/backend/src/licenses/license/license.repo.ts:119:21)
1|jhdms  |       at /jhdms/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
1|jhdms  |       at /jhdms/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17 {
1|jhdms  |     length: 117,
1|jhdms  |     severity: 'ERROR',
1|jhdms  |     code: '22021',
1|jhdms  |     detail: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     hint: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     position: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     internalPosition: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     internalQuery: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     where: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     schema: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     table: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     column: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     dataType: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     constraint: undefined,
1|jhdms  |     file: 'mbutils.c',
1|jhdms  |     line: '1665',
1|jhdms  |     routine: 'report_invalid_encoding'
1|jhdms  |   },
1|jhdms  |   length: 117,
1|jhdms  |   severity: 'ERROR',
1|jhdms  |   code: '22021',
1|jhdms  |   detail: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   hint: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   position: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   internalPosition: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   internalQuery: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   where: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   schema: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   table: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   column: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   dataType: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   constraint: undefined,
1|jhdms  |   file: 'mbutils.c',
1|jhdms  |   line: '1665',
1|jhdms  |   routine: 'report_invalid_encoding'
1|jhdms  | }
i tried to review db data, and nothing wrong.

exact error facing : invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0

Happened to me yesterday and it's reported in here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/54543
The problem is with 22.7 version, reverting to older versions will fix the issue, we wait until node fixes it in next releases.
